# Variables in PHP gettext

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext, po

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does gettext handle dynamic content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773023/how-does-gettext-handle-dynamic-content)

I'm using PHP's gettext.  I want to translate a sentence which has a variable in it. Is this possible?

For example, in English:

`Are you sure you want to block Alice?`

(Where "Alice" is the user's name.)

But, in German, the subject does not appear at the end of the sentence.

`Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie Alice blockieren?`

In messages.po, I have

```
msgid "BLOCK"
msgstr "Are you sure you want to block"
```

But I see no way to pass one or more variables.  Is this possible?

Comment: Placeholdrs like `%s` and `sprintf` or alike are commonly used for that. Also you should not use ABBReviations for the gettext source string. Use plain English for the untranslated messages. Messages seldomly change in practice, and the gettext catalogs can be easily adapted if it ever happens.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

poedit recognizes the vars.

```
msgid "Are you sure you want to block %s?"
msgstr "Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie %s blockieren?"
```

and in PHP

```
sprintf(_('Are you sure you want to block %s?'),'Alice');
```

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks. Have edited to show sprintf.  printf just shows the length.

Comment: Sprintf? Why? Printf print the string and sprintf return it. Maybe you write `echo sprintf`.

Comment: @chumkiu - `sprintf()` is probably used here for reasons that are irrelevant to gettext and localization.  (The app itself probably needed to store/manipulate the resulting string, not output it directly to stdout.)

Comment: Can do do something like this with `<?= __('key') ?>`?