# Wordpress translation with split sentences

Tags: php, string, wordpress, localization, internationalization

I've been going through the process of making my theme translation ready and have already done most of the strings, but I've only just now been made aware that is is best to use full sentences.

I understand why, and it's because the translator won't know if the two or more different strings are supposed to form a single sentence, and he could provide a translation that is incorrect, out of context, whatever.

So if I have something like this in my theme...

```
<?php _e( "You have", "my-theme" ); ?> <?php echo $hours;?> <?php _e( "hours and", "my-theme" ); ?> <?php echo $minutes;?> <?php _e( "minutes remaining", "my-theme" ); ?>
```

(FYI the variables just return numbers)

...a translator is going to be asked to translate these 3 strings...

```
You have
hours and
minutes remaining
```

...which in English won't be a big deal combined, but in a different language when all three of those strings are translated separately, then output on a page combined to form a single sentence it might not give the correct intended meaning.

So I guess my question is: is there a better way than the example I provided above? To me this seems like an unavoidable situation, but I'm open to suggestions.

Also on a related note, is it a big deal to have one or two word strings? My theme has many instances of those as well. Like form labels for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does gettext handle dynamic content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773023/how-does-gettext-handle-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php printf( __( 'You have %1$d hours and %2$d minutes remaining.' ), $hours, $minutes); ?>
```

if it is not working then try

```
<?php printf( _e( 'You have %1$d hours and %2$d minutes remaining.' ), $hours, $minutes); ?>
```

You can also [refer](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)